# ESLint is not a constructor

Tags: webpack, eslint

I have made the porting to eslint-webpack-plugin and I am getting the error "ESLint is not a constructor", the relevant snippet code is:

```
const ESLintPlugin = require('eslint-webpack-plugin');

  const plugins = [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(productionEnvironmentVariables),
    new ESLintPlugin({
      overrideConfigFile: path.resolve(configPath, '.eslintrc.json')
    })
  ];
```

Any idea what is wrong? I have tried also with new ESLintPlugin() and ESLintPlugin({}).

Webpack version is ^4.44.2
Eslint version is ^6.8.0
eslint-webpack-plugin is ^2.1.0

Thank you in advance and regards.

Comment: Update ESLint to version 7.

Comment: Thanks @GuyIncognito that made it work!

Comment: Anyone know why this fixses it?

Comment: Probably because when I installed eslint-webpack-plugin I installed automatically the latest version of it and I did not update the rest of my packages, including Eslint. When you do that there are high chances there is gonna be incompatible versions between your dependencies if they depend on each other.

Comment: Did the same, now getting the following error:
TypeError: Class constructor ESLintWebpackPlugin cannot be invoked without 'new'.
Any clue?

Answer (score 42):

You also need to install eslint >= 7 from npm, if you haven't already:

npm

```
npm i -D eslint@7.32.0
```

yarn

```
yarn add -D eslint@7.32.0
```

Comment: The command would be `npm i eslint@7.32.0`

Comment: `npm i eslint@latest` for last version

Comment: Installing the latest eslint (v8) didn't fix the issue for me. v7.32.0 worked perfectly though.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error while building vue app and had node > v18 .This worked for me eslint@7.32.0 .But not the latest eslint
version  installation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Just install eslint pack with the latest version, it work for me.

```
npm i eslint@latest -D
```